# How do I change properties of a new spawned in object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to programming and right now I'm working on a 2D-Game for Android with Unity. The basic concept right now is that a object moves to the middle of the screen and it needs to "touch" an other object so you can press on a button and the moving object is getting destroyed. After it got destroyed I want another to spawn in and keep that cycle going. There is my problem. I have the (moving) object as a prefab and added it as the public GameObject "RedTriangle". The object is getting spawned in and moves to the center of the screen but it doesn't change the layer of the new objects when I press the button (I guess because its not the same object as the "RedTriangle" object). I really don't know how to change the Layer of new spawned in objects and hope I can get help here. Thanks already for all responses.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Red : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
     public GameObject RedTriangle;
     public GameObject FalseTriangle;
     public Transform spawnPos;
     public float spawnT;


     private void Start()
     {
         GameObject newTriangle = Instantiate(RedTriangle, spawnPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
     }
     IEnumerator touchCD()
     {
         while (true)
         {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
             if (RedTriangle == null)
             {
             }
             else if (RedTriangle != null)
             {
                 Debug.Log("!= null");
                 RedTriangle.layer = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     public void Update()
     {
         if (RedTriangle == null)
         {
             spawnT = Random.Range(1, 4);
             if (spawnT == 3)
             {
                 GameObject newTriangle = Instantiate(FalseTriangle, spawnPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
             }
             else
             {
                 GameObject newFalseTriangle = Instantiate(RedTriangle, spawnPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
             }
         }
     }
     public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         RedTriangle.layer = 7;
         Debug.Log("button");
         StartCoroutine(touchCD());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change the layer of the object immediately after spawning, just do exactly that. For example:

```
GameObject newTriangle = Instantiate(FalseTriangle, spawnPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
newTriangle.layer = 0;
```

If you want to change the current (MonoBehaviour) object's own layer from its own attached component script e.g. when a certain event occurs, you don't need to keep the reference in your own variable as you can just use for example:

```
gameObject.layer = 0;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I think i didnt make it clear, but this is the script for the "button". I want to change the layer of an spawned in object when i press this button. 
Or maybe i just misunderstood ur response. :/

Comment: If you want to spawn a new item and set its layer when you press the button, use something like the code at the top of the answer. If you want it to change an object that was spawned previously: Sounds like there are several spawned in items. Is there a button for each one? If not, what is your intended criteria for which one is changed by the button? Or do you want to change all of them at once when the button is pressed?

Comment: I found a way to solve my problem. Still, thanks for the response. :)

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Well instead of adding the prefab (from my assets) as the GameObject "RedTriangle", I used the prefab object when I dragged it in the scene. ("RedTriangle(Clone)")

Comment: Sorry for explaining it this poorly, but my english isn't the best. ^^